# Unity won't start - could not establish connection to Unity Package Manager local server process

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I got this error using unity 2019.4.3f1. I tried with unity 2019.3.15f1, but the same error pops out.
After looking in other forums i tried using "setx UNITY_NOPROXY" in the cmd. This was a solution to many people,but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off wifi then launch then turn it back on